# SerializationException Unable to find assembly

Tags: .net, serialization, binary-serialization

I need to know if is possible serialize an object of type AssemblyA.MyType and deserialize the file to type AssemblyB.MyType.
These two types are identicals, the only difference is the location that it's stored(AssemblyA and AssemblyB).

My scenario:
AssemblyA is used by an executable, **ExeA**, thats need a lot of types and functions.
AssemblyB is user by **ExeB**, and just need of MyType (and can't contain any other reference that is on AssemblyA)

I think if I create a third assembly (AssemblyC) that contains MyType, I remove MyType from AssemblyA and AssemblyB, and add reference AssemblyC to my two projects.
But is possible serialize and deserialize using different types?

I'm using net 2.0

Thank you.